# Observe particular data sets of Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase to implement a iOS anonymous chat app.

My app has a list of chatting rooms and click the room will join a group chat likes Facebook messenger.
the structure of database looks like

```
rooms
  |- AAA
     |- messages
        |- "aaaaa"
        |- "bbbbb"
        |- "ccccc"
  |- BBB
     |- messages
        |- "ddddd"
        |- "eeeee"
  |- CCC
     |- messages
        |- "fffff"
        |- "ggggg"
  ...
```

If user join the rooms, for example `AAA` and `BBB`. App will store `AAA` and `BBB` in local storage. How can I observe the new messages have added to `AAA` or `BBB` but not observe `CCC`?

I read the documents of Firebase. I may have some methods to do that.

1. observe whole `rooms` node and filter `AAA` and `BBB` in app. But I think it will cause a performance issue if there are too many `rooms`. The data size is so big.
2. create separate observers for `AAA` and `BBB`. It may solve my problem but if my user join too many `rooms`. Observing many nodes looks like not make sense.
3. Set a rule to control which `rooms` can be synced. But I have to record that a user enter a room. And I have to manage the relations of anonymous user and chats.

Is there any way with better performance can solve my problem?

maybe likes

```
['AAA', 'BBB'].observe(.childAdded, {
    // do something
})
```

Or any suggestions are welcome!

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database observers always retrieve whole nodes. There is no way to retrieve partial nodes, beyond the abilities of a query. But in your case you can't use a query, since you can't do an `OR` in a query and the chat rooms may not be in a range.

If you are trying to ensure that the rooms the user is in are cached for when they are offline, you can [call `keepSynced(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) on each room. This will essentially add an empty listener that ensures the (disk) cache stays up to date.

If you want to show multiple chat rooms at sone, you will need to use multiple observers for that: one for each room.